# How to access javabean in gwt module( client + server) from outside gwt module?

Tags: java, gwt, javabeans, gwt-rpc

I want to access javabean(VO) in gwt module(client & server ) from outside module ( non-gwt module).

How to access, used that javabean in gwt module?

Any solution for this case ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a *.gwt.xml somewhere in the package hierarchy of the class you want to use on the client-side; that is, you have to make it appear in a GWT module, and `<inherit/>` that module.

Comment: Hey Thomas, Thanks for your answer. But the class that we want to re-use, is general business class and not belonging to any GWT module.. How can we mention it in <inherit /> tag?

Comment: "You have to create *.gwt.xml somewhere in the package hierarchy of the class you want to use" (and note it's package-hierarchy, not folder-hierarchy: it's loaded from the classpath, it does not need to even be in the JAR containing the class)